# Unite Columns Into an Array in Impala

Tags: hive, impala

In Hive is a possibility to unite columns into an array like :

```
select array(*) from my_table
```

The output will be an array per row with all columns values. How can I achieve the same result in Impala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Impala does not support any way to create complex objects (array,structures or maps). You will need to perform your ingestion using Hive/Spark or any other alternative.